# Confuse for the Median, First and Third Quartile

Tags: statistics

[image: Grouped data]

The question asks me to calculate the median, 1st and 3rd quartile.
The formula found in net for median which is $$L+\frac{\frac{1}{2}n-cf_b}{fm}\cdot w$$ where $L$ is the lower class boundary of the group containing the median, $n$ is the total number of data, $cf_b$ is the cumulative frequency of the groups before the median group, $f_m$ is the frequency of the median group and $w$ is the group width. The formulas for $Q_1$ and $Q_3$ are a bit different only which is $\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$ instead of $\frac{1}{2}$

So my attempt,

Median$=2+(\frac{16}{17})1=2.35$

$Q_1=1+(\frac{\frac{9}{2}}{11})*1=1.41$

$Q_3=3+(\frac{\frac{3}{2}}{8})*2=3.4$.

But my answers are different from others for $Q_1$ and $Q_3$ which are $1.45$ and $3.5$. Why? Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no universal definition of percentiles, so it may be that the definition you're using is different to the one you're quoting those values of $Q_1$ and $Q_3$.

It looks like your source is using the Nearest Rank Method (read more here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile#The_Nearest_Rank_method).

So for $n=50$, we calculate the 25th percentile, $Q_1$ as follows
$$n_1=\left \lceil{\frac{25}{100}\times 50}\right \rceil = \left \lceil{12.5}\right \rceil=13$$
Then applying the formula you quote, noting that datum number $13$ is within the range $1<x\leq2$, $Q_1=\frac{5}{11}\times 1+1=1.\overline{45}$.

Similarly for the 75th percentile $n_2=\left \lceil{37.5}\right \rceil=38$, then note the 38th datum is within the range $3<x\leq 5$, $Q_3=\frac{2}{8}\times 2+3=3.5$.